# Мониторинг сервера

Tags: python, django

Не однократно предпринимал попытки, понять и получить подробную инфу, но не как не выходит.

На сервере стоит сайт:
Python2.6, Dango1.3, lighttpd, postgresql, memcached. Так же используется шаблонный кешь средствами Django.

Сайт посещает в день 10К - 15К пользователей, это стабильно 100 человек онлайн, в пики, поднимается до 400 - 600 человек онлайном.

На сервере (выделенный):
4Гб ОЗУ, Intel Core i3-2100, debian

Python запущен method=prefork

Когда посещаемость переваливает за 300 онлайн, то сервер начинает тупить (проц 95% занят, ОЗУ 200Мб свободно). Он работает, но ответа иногда не дождаться. Через django-toolbar-debug запросов сильно тяжёлых нет, 100мс-200мс максимальные.

Собственно вопрос: Как можно ещё кроме django-toolbar-debug проанализировать что может тупить в двиге сайта? Может кто-то досит, как это увидеть? Возможны ещё причины, возможно ПО на котором развернуть сайт, лучше другая будет?

Поделитесь своими мыслями на счет этого, админы, за любое мнение буду очень благодарен. (Сам далёк от администрирования, программист и на win).

Answer (score 3):

Пробуйте смотреть нагрузку на процессор, сеть и дисковую подсистему, соответственно - htop, iftop и iotop.

Comment: Дождался нагрузки, когда сайт начинает тупить, посмотрел командами что вы сказали, но ничего не понял, по htop видно что всё на 100% загруженно, много питонов, по iftop беспрерывный поток IP, вроде все разные, нет постоянных чтобы видно было что досят. ну и iotop - в основном там postgres и lighthttpd, ну оно то и понятно, они же с файловой системой работают. В целом понял что именно проц с памятью на гране.В эти моменты нагрузки, некоторым пользователям страницы отдаются, остальным выкидывает ошибку 500. Когда нагрузка падает, то все в норме.Может как то по другому настроить python?

Comment: Я правильно понял, htop говорит что скрипты питона грузят цпу на 100% ?Через питоновские скрипты выполняются SQL запросы? Посмотрите здесь http://postgresmen.ru/articles/view/38

Comment: Обязательно всё прочту, попробую, потом отпишу.Однако как писал в вопросе, через django-toolbar-debug смотрю запросы, ничего тяжёлого там нет, все в десятки миллисекунд укладываются. А время процессора показывает 1 с лишним секунды, общее время 6 секунд.

Comment: @trec, ну так [профилируйте-же](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango)!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что проблема не программная, а аппаратная. Нужно пересмотреть железо, которое используется на сервере. Первое, что бы я сделал - добавил ОЗУ и диски в RAID 5.